# Make Tabs on ActionBar scroll when reach limit, rather than create a dropdown-list

Tags: android, tabs, scroll, android-actionbar

As the title suggests, I have an Android 4.0 Tablet app, that uses the Actionbar and tab mode.

If I add any more than 4 or 5 tabs to the action bar, a dropdown list is created instead. I have read the documentation, which states, "Note: In some cases, the Android system will show your action bar tabs as a drop-down list in order to ensure the best fit in the action bar."

Was just wondering if it is possible to override the default behavior and get the actionbar to scroll the items? The design document http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html talks about scrollable tabs, but I can't seem to find any information on them other than in the design document.

Comment: I have done some more digging see: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=24439 and it seems it isn't possible. Now looking for alternative approaches

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been struggling to get this to work. However, after playing with ActionBarSherlock, the solution is infuriatingly easy. If you download the sample Styled source and look in the MainActivity class, you can see it create and add the tabs, and beneath that:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

I had called these BEFORE adding the tabs, and my tabs had been turned into a drop-down list. Turns out, all you need to do is call them after adding the tabs instead to keep the scrolling tabs.

Comment: Not the answer I was after, but it appears as of now, it's the only way to do what I wanted.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I still see the dropdown list instead of the tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Read the "Adding an Action View" section from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

> An action view is a widget that appears in the action bar as a substitute for an action item's button.

You can use `HorizontalScrollView` as action view by specifying

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/mytabwidget"
      android:title=""
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.HorizontalScrollView" />
</menu>
```

Get reference to this `HorizontalScrollView` in `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

Define a `RadioGroup` with some `RadioButton` where each `RadioButton` when selected, will update its associated tabs contents. Now add this `RadioGroup` to `HorizontalScrollView` which you will get in `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

You can use `selectTab(ActionBar.Tab tab)` or some other equivalent method to update tabs contents.

You can change the look of `RadioButton` by setting `android:button` to transparent image and then setting some `StateListDrawable` with states checked, selected and normal..

See below screen I got using this method.

[image]

In above image, each `RadioButton` when checked, selects different tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the Honeycomb Gallery sample app in the SDK? It might have what you are looking for. Install it on an ICS non-tablet device to see the scrollable tabs. A tablet has too much screen space for it to scroll.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/index.html

Comment: I want it to scroll on a tablet too - I added 5 more tabs to the above project and it condensed into a menu too. PITA

Answer (score -1):

The UI works the way it is for a reason.  It is extremely confusing to have a scrollable set of tabs.  There is a good chance that it won't be clear at all that there are more tabs available on the right, and the user will never know they can scroll the tabs to get to more features.

I recommend sticking with how the platform is designed to work.  It generally does things for a reason.

Comment: You might wish to point out to those in charge of the Android Design pages, then, that what [they describe as "scrollable tabs" related to the "action bar"](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) are neither. What they describe appears to be `ViewPager` and some title strip that doesn't exist in the SDK (since `PagerTitleStrip` is display-only and therefore cannot really be considered a "tab"). It is frustrating for developers to be given design guidelines that Google itself does not agree with (per your answer here) and/or are not supported by the SDK.

Comment: Taken from the Android design document, "Use scrollable tabs if you have a large number of views..." From my point of view, in the app that we are building, it isn't at all confusing having that number of tabs. Surely in an "open" platform, it should be up to the developer to chose what is appropriate for their app, not the OS. Our app is a vertical that will never be used by untrained users.

Comment: Also, how is scrolling tabs any more confusing than a scrolling list that we have to implement as a work around? It's not obvious that their are things at under the last item in the list either.